# jQuery collapsible UL

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a navigation system using jQuery. What I want to achieve is having the parent elements visible on the page load and the child elements hidden. Which I have done very simply.

However when I toggle between the other parent elements I want to be able to hide the previous child elements so that I can only open up one `<ul>` at a time.

```js
//user nav
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightBottom">
<h1 class="boxheadings">Other functions</h1>
<p class="boxp">Click this button to view your current published site in a new window. This will not show your most recent changes until you click the ‘Publish Changes’ button on the right, alternatively click view local to see unpublished changes.</p>
<ul id="usernav">
    <li class="parent">Manage
        <ul class="child">
            <li>child11</li>
            <li>child12</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Subscriptions
        <ul class="child">
            <li>E-Briefings</li>
            <li>E-Briefings Subscriptions</li>
            <li>Knowledge Briefings</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Media Store
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Image Store</li>
            <li>Document Store</li>
            <li>Media Store</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

done . it was very simple. I am hiding everything before showing the current ul.

see :

```
//hide all children initially
$('.child').hide();

//adding a click handlers to every all parents
$('.parent').click(function() {

   //slide up the children which are open already
   $('.child').slideUp();

   //find the child of clicked parent and toggle its visibility
   $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: You can't re-collapse the last expanded list with this, it just toggles it

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
$('.child').hide();
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.parent').find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    });
```

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9kn/1/)

Comment: I missed the `find('ul')` when also trying to answer, else I'd have answered exactly this. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just collapse all the `UL`s before you expand any one:

Add this line before you do a slideToggle:

```
$('#usernav').find('ul').slideUp();

$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').click(function() {
    $('#usernav').find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```